# Pass a variable into a SQL query in Excel Power Query

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

Long story short, I have a sql query pulling data from a database into a spreadsheet. I want to be able to change the Plant filter inside the query via Power Query, I have tried using a custom function and adding that into the query where the variable is set (see below)

```
Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="DECLARE @FilterOnPlant AS varchar(3)#(lf)SET @FilterOnPlant = '" + filterOnPlant + "'#(lf)#(lf)SELECT
```

In doing this I keep getting the following error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator + to types Text and Table.
Details:
    Operator=+
    Left=DECLARE @FilterOnPlant AS varchar(3)
SET @FilterOnPlant = '
    Right=[Table]
```

I figure it has something to do with the '+' operator used but can't find an alternative.

I have tried using:

- '&'
- '+'
- 'and'

but they all yield the same error (with the exception of 'and' that error states that it's not being used in a logical statement which makes sense)

For further info:

The custom function to get the value I want is:

```
filterOnPlant = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Active_Plant"]}[Content]
```

The intention is to get the Value from a cell Named "Active_Plant"

**EDIT:**

after further testing I have found the issue lies with variable filterOnPlant, when I exchange that for a string value then the query works as expected. If anyone knows how I can get CELL().Value of a named range in power query would be super helpful

Comment: `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()...[Content]` returns a table. You may either concatenate its rows with `Text.Combine` or if you have a single-row table, use `List.First(Excel...[Content][Column1])`

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

In my filterOnPlant function I was missing `{0}[Column1]`

Original: `filterOnPlant = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Active_Plant"]}[Content]`

New (Working): `filterOnPlant = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Active_Plant"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]`